# Wishlist Button works only when force page refresh and not working when selecting calender date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me to solve this jquery issue.

When a class is full then you can see "Waitlist Only" content. Previously Book Button is shown for "Waitlist Only". So When the document is ready, I wrote code to hide the button and instead append anchor tag with Wishlist as content. But the problem is that sometimes only after Force page refresh the wishlist button is visible. ie; my jquery code is not getting updated, it will get updated only when force page refresh. Also when selecting a date on the calender, my code doesn't works, like when i selected date Oct 19 and then selected Oct 18 I am not able to see the Wishlist Button I have created using jquery.

Link: https://www.skycandyaustin.com/class/circus-fitness/

This is the snipped code created.

```
(function ($) {

$("div.bw-session:has(span.hc_waitlist)").each(function () {
  $(this).find(".bw-widget__signup-now").hide();
      $("span.bw-widget__cart_button", this).append("<a class=\"hc-button signup_now bw-widget__signup-now bw-widget__cta\" href=\"mailto:"
        + scConfig.waitlistEmail + "?subject=Waitlist for "
        + $('div.bw-session__name', this).text().replace(reWhitespace, ' ')
        + '&body=Hello%2c Please add me to the waitlist for '
        + $('div.bw-session__name', this).text().replace(reWhitespace, ' ')
        + " on " + $(this).parent().children('.bw-widget__date').text().replace(reWhitespace, ' ')
        + " with " + $("div.bw-session__staff", this).text()
        + ".\">Waitlist</a>");
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research, found the solution. Javascript track changes in DOM using Mutation Observer. MutationObserver is a Web API provided by modern browsers for detecting changes in the DOM. With this API one can listen to newly added or removed nodes, attribute changes or changes in the text content of text nodes. You need to create a MutationObserver instance by passing it a function that would be called every time a mutation has occurred.  The first argument of the function is a collection of all mutations which have occurred in a single batch. Each mutation provides information about its type and the changes which have occurred.

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation);
  });
});
```

The created object has three methods: observe , disconnect , takeRecords

These are the options used in MutationObserver.
childList, attributes, characterData, subtree etc.

When check found that If subtree Set to true if mutations to not just target, but also target's descendants are to be observed. So added the same and it worked! OMG Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Your code only works when the page is first loaded, when you click a calendar date, it requests data and replaces the existing classes. You need to call your function again everytime you click a calendar date.

Add this to your code;

```
<script>

function replaceBookToWait(){

  $("div.bw-session:has(span.hc_waitlist)").each(function () {
    $(this).find(".bw-widget__signup-now").hide();
    $("span.bw-widget__cart_button", this).append("<a class=\"hc-button signup_now bw-widget__signup-now bw-widget__cta\" href=\"mailto:"
    + scConfig.waitlistEmail + "?subject=Waitlist for "
    + $('div.bw-session__name', this).text().replace(reWhitespace, ' ')
    + '&body=Hello%2c Please add me to the waitlist for '
    + $('div.bw-session__name', this).text().replace(reWhitespace, ' ')
    + " on " + $(this).parent().children('.bw-widget__date').text().replace(reWhitespace, ' ')
    + " with " + $("div.bw-session__staff", this).text()
    + ".\">Waitlist</a>");
  });

}

// when the page is first loaded, replace the book button
$(document).ready(replaceBookToWait);    

// after calendar click, replace the book button
$(document).on("click",".bw-calendar__day>span",replaceBookToWait);

</script>
```

Comment: Will you put this line of code at the end of the body tag? Try to put it as the last script.

I can't test too because I can't find any 'Waitlist' button on your site.

Comment: Do you know how to update the code when selecting date from mindbody widget calender? Kindly please help me.